# VIew onMeasure infinite loop without any action taken

Tags: android, android-layout

First, I'd like to assure you that I've read tons of similar posts on SO and answer to MY question is yet to be found.

So, the question (or I should say the problem):
I have a list view with pretty tricky items with text views, buttons, edit texts inside them. All these items are generated dynamically. Yes, I have the worst and buggiest (is there such word?) thing you can imagine in Android developement. So, to control all this mess I have the Hell Machine, that holds all info about focuses, cursor positions in edit texts and other cool stuff. It is really a very big bunch of code and I'm sure no one of you wants to see it, also it's top-secret (joking).

So, the PROBLEM. When I tap on edit text to type smth in it, my Adapter's method getView() begins getting called about 200 hundred of times endlessly (i.e. in a loop). Though, it does not affect text input or something else, but this is completely not normal. While debugging, I saw that onMeasure() method eventually calles my getView(), and then (for some reason) goes into a loop.

So my question is: how is this even possible that onMeasure goes into a loop? I just tapped on edit text and nothing else, I do not input any data in it, I don't scroll my list, I don't even touch my phone and it does not move by itself.

I feel myself bad for not giving you the whole code I have, so at least I'll give you the stack trace of the onMeasure() method.

```
StaticLayout(Layout).getWidth() line: 537   
TextView.onMeasure(int, int) line: 6188 
TextView(View).measure(int, int) line: 15172    
LinearLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4816    
LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(View, int, int, int, int, int) line: 1390 
LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(int, int) line: 1038 
LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 576  
LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 15172    
HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 1216   
HorizontalScrollView(FrameLayout).onMeasure(int, int) line: 310 
HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(int, int) line: 299  
HorizontalScrollView(View).measure(int, int) line: 15172    
RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(View, RelativeLayout$LayoutParams, int, int) line: 617    
RelativeLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 399    
RelativeLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 15172  
FrameLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4816 
FrameLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 310   
FrameLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 15172 
LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 833    
LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 574  
LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 15172    
PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int, int) line: 4816   
PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).onMeasure(int, int) line: 310    
PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(int, int) line: 2220    
PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).measure(int, int) line: 15172   
ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(int, int) line: 1850    
ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(View, WindowManager$LayoutParams, Resources, int, int) line: 1102 
ViewRootImpl.performTraversals() line: 1275 
ViewRootImpl.doTraversal() line: 1000   
ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run() line: 4214 
Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(long) line: 725    
Choreographer.doCallbacks(int, long) line: 555  
Choreographer.doFrame(long, int) line: 525  
Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run() line: 711 
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 615   
Choreographer$FrameHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92   
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4787    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 789  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 556 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because of ListView's layout_height value = wrap_content. Setting this to fill_parent fixed the issue